# object property values for individuals in Jena

Tags: jena, ontology, owl, protege

I have created an ontology using Protégé. Using Jena, I am creating an individual and assigning values for its properties.  Datatype properties can be created using `getOntProperty(String uri)`, but using the same method I cannot create object properties. Which method can be used to create object properties and  add values for an object property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getOntProperty(String)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#getOntProperty%28java.lang.String%29) is an OntModel method for *creating* or *retrieving* properties from an ontology, not for making property assertions about Individuals.  For datatype properties, you should probably be using [getDatatypeProperty(String)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#getDatatypeProperty%28java.lang.String%29) instead.  For object properties, you should use [getObjectProperty(String)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#getObjectProperty%28java.lang.String%29).  All of these methods are described in the documentation.  Once you have a property, you can use the methods that an Individual inherits from [Resource](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html#addProperty%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode%29) to add properties values.  In particular, you'd want the addProperty and addLiteral methods.